# How to determine which API Permissions are necessary to run a particular Azure PowerShell command?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, az

I have a service principal that I use for automation.  It has the `Directory.Read.All` permission in Microsoft Graph for our Azure Active Directory.

It cannot run the `Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator` command.  The error I get is:

```
Cannot find the Azure Active Directory object 'My-AD-Group'.
Please make sure that the user or group you are authorizing is
registered in the current subscription's Azure Active directory.
```

If I run this same command as myself, it runs just fine.

Clearly my Service Principal needs more than the `Directory.Read.All` permission.  Yet I cannot find any documentation that lists exactly what API Permissions my Service Principal would need to successfully run this command.

Does anyone know how I can discover exactly what API permissions would be required to run a particular Azure PowerShell command that involves accessing Azure Active Directory?

As an aside, I'm not tied to PowerShell.  I cannot get this command to work with the `az` cli either.  I'm open to methods using `az` that would get me this answer.

Comment: I dont think there is a comprehensive list somewhere. I might be wrong, but I've never seen it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `Directory.Read.All`(Application permission) of *Azure AD Graph API* not the *Microsoft Graph API*. Also make sure the service principal has the permission of the sql server(e.g. the service principal is the `Owner` of the subscription or the sql server), then it will work fine.

If you want to add the service principal as a role of the subscription or sql server, navigate to the subscription or the sql server in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search your service principal with name and add it as a role(e.g. `Owner`) -> `Save`, more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

[image]

```
Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -ServerName "<ServerName>" -DisplayName "group1" -ObjectId "64d1b8xxxxx4ffbd"
```

[image]

> Does anyone know how I can discover exactly what API permissions would be required to run a particular Azure PowerShell command that involves accessing Azure Active Directory?

The Azure PowerShell essentially calls the different APIs, to get the permissions of the APIs, you could catch the request via [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), then look into the official API doc for the permissions.

Comment: Thanks, Joy.  That was in fact my problem.  I discovered it myself when I noticed that there were API calls going to graph.windows.net instead of graph.windows.com and had to look up the difference.  Once I granted the correct permissions, everything started working.

Comment: Great answer but where do you find out what permissions apply to different actions?